# AWS query string does not extract any data when executed by .sh script

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, bash, ubuntu, git-bash

I'm new to Bash scripting and would like to test extracting a data, my plan is to extract data to a .txt file base on the aws query from .sh file (bashscript). I have a bigger purpose but I want to have this work first before I input my main aws query.

**I have a .sh script here below.**

**NOTE: I put all values to -confidential- without any quotations. Just the value**

```
#!/bin/bash

variables () {
lambdas="confidential"
}
variables

queryId=$(aws logs start-query --log-group-name $lambdas --start-time 1695704400 --end-time 1695707999 --query-string 'filter @message like "requestId" | parse @message "operationName: '*'," as API | parse @message "status: *," as Status | parse @message "channel: '*'," as Channel | stats count(*) as Total by API,Channel,Status | sort API,Total desc' | jq '.queryId' | awk -F '"' '{print $2}')


results=$(aws logs get-query-results --query-id $queryId | jq .)


echo "$results" > testextract5.txt
```

**Whenever I run that .sh file, this is the result .txt below:**

```
{
  "results": [],
  "statistics": {
    "recordsMatched": 0,
    "recordsScanned": 0,
    "bytesScanned": 0
  },
  "status": "Running"
}
```

**BUT when I manually copy paste each command from .sh file all the bash script in the git-bash command line, it works! See below:**

```
jomasangkay@DESKTOP-R1DM530:/mnt/c/Users/personal pc/Desktop/company/Bashscript/test$ queryId=$(aws logs start-query --log-group-name $lambdas --start-time 1695704400 --end-time 1695707999 --query-string 'filter @message like "requestId" | parse @message "operationName: '*'," as API | parse @message "status: *," as Status | parse @message "channel: '*'" as Channel | stats count(*) as Total by API,Channel,Status | sort API,Total desc' | jq '.queryId' | awk -F '"' '{print $2}')
jomasangkay@DESKTOP-R1DM530:/mnt/c/Users/personal pc/Desktop/company/Bashscript/test$ results=$(aws logs get-query-results --query-id $queryId | jq .)
jomasangkay@DESKTOP-R1DM530:/mnt/c/Users/personal pc/Desktop/company/Bashscript/test$ echo "$results" > testextract5.txt
```

**RESULT extracted .txt below,**

```
     {
        "field": "API",
        "value": "'Confidential'"
      },
      {
        "field": "Channel",
        "value": "'Confidential'"
      },
      {
        "field": "Status",
        "value": "Confidential"
      },
      {
        "field": "Total",
        "value": "1"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "statistics": {
    "recordsMatched": 16507,
    "recordsScanned": 69000,
    "bytesScanned": 29835564
  },
  "status": "Complete"
}
```

Action taken/Future Plan:

I tried to troubleshoot and used a bash -x script.sh but I don't see any issue at all. I tried to rollback to wsl version 1, installed latest update of aws cli. None of it works. Is there something wrong with my script?

I'm expecting that when I run the .sh file, there should be the expected data like the above .txt RESULT. My main purpose creating this bash script is because AWS Cloudwatch Log insights has a limitation related to lambda , so i plan to create a bash script , using array in $lambda . This post is for my trial and error only. I need to make this work to move forward.

==========================

Tried the double quotation for $lambda and $queryId, same result no data. below

```
jomasangkay@DESKTOP-R1DM530:/mnt/c/Users/personal pc/Desktop/company/Bashscript/test$ bash -x testing2.sh
+ variables
+ lambdas=confidential
++ jq .queryId
++ awk -F '"' '{print $2}'
++ aws logs start-query --log-group-name confidential --start-time 1695704400 --end-time 1695707999 --query-string 'filter @message like "requestId" | parse @message "operationName: *," as API | parse @message "status: *," as Status | parse @message "channel: *," as Channel | stats count(*) as Total by API,Channel,Status | sort API,Total desc'
+ queryId=0f6c6fd6-da5e-40ed-9c74-ad22791455be
++ aws logs get-query-results --query-id 0f6c6fd6-da5e-40ed-9c74-ad22791455be
++ jq .
+ results='{
  "results": [],
  "statistics": {
    "recordsMatched": 0,
    "recordsScanned": 0,
    "bytesScanned": 0
  },
  "status": "Running"
}'
+ echo '{
  "results": [],
  "statistics": {
    "recordsMatched": 0,
    "recordsScanned": 0,
    "bytesScanned": 0
  },
  "status": "Running"
}'
```

===============================

Updated as of Oct 3, 2023 - 05:15 AM SINGAPORE TIME

I isolated the issue by creating a 2 .txt file called test1.txt and test2.txt , and their contents below,

```
test1.txt
c86c7f6b-95e4-4d17-9417-2f6987989316
```

```
test2.txt
c86c7f6b-95e4-4d17-9417-2f6987989316
```

As you can see above they have the exact same value (no spaces, no unusual text or whatsoever.)

**See may new modified code below,**

```
#!/bin/bash

variables () {
lambdas="confidential"

}
variables

queryId=$(aws logs start-query --log-group-name "$lambdas" --start-time 1695704400 --end-time 1695707999 --query-string 'filter @message like "requestId"' | jq '.queryId' | awk -F '"' '{print $2}')

#NOT WORKING
echo $queryId > test1.txt

#WORKING
echo c86c7f6b-95e4-4d17-9417-2f6987989316 > test2.txt


queryIds=$(awk '{print $1}' test2.txt)

results=$(aws logs get-query-results --query-id $queryIds | jq .)

echo "$results" > testextract.txt
```

When i assigned the variable from test1.txt, its not working no data extracted.

When i assigned the variable from test2.txt, its working as expected.

For some reason, looks like the value from test1.txt query id converted to somewhat special character, im not sure.

Comment: Hello Ermiya good day apologies I've converted the image into text now. Im not sure on how i should format my questions. But ill try, im new to this forum

Comment: No worries! Thank you so much for formatting, that's much better and no need to apologise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Repeat `aws logs get-query-results` until results are available

As we see in the updated output in the question, the response to `aws logs get-query-results` has `"status": "Running"`. The query is simply still running on AWS, the results are not ready yet, not available to download. So we just need to call `aws logs get-query-results` again a bit later.

As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueryResults.html), the valid status values are `Scheduled | Running | Complete | Failed | Cancelled | Timeout | Unknown`. You can try to get the results repeatedly in a loop until the status is not one of `Scheduled` or `Running`:

```
while true; do
    results=$(aws logs get-query-results --query-id "$queryId" | jq .)
    status=$(jq -r .status <<< "$results")
    echo "status=$status"
    [ "$status" = "Scheduled" -o "$status" = "Running" ] || break
    sleep 1
done
```

#### The red herring

Originally, this part looked suspicious Bash:

> ```
> queryId=$(aws ... 'filter ... operationName: '*', ... channel: '*', ...' | ...)
>                                              ^^^               ^^^
> ```

That is, a "naked" `*`, outside of the single-quoted expression, which looks unintentional, and error prone.

The intention seems to be to include `'*'` inside the single-quoted expression, which we can do by ending the ongoing single-quoted expression which started at `'filter ...` by adding a single-quote, then adding `'*'` in a double-quoted expression, and then start another single-quoted expression to continue the one we interrupted:

```
queryId=$(aws ... 'filter ... operationName: '"'*'"', ... channel: '"'*'"', ...' | ...)
                                             ^ ending the previous single-quoted expression
                                              ^^^^^ a double-quoted expression
                                                   ^ starting a new single-quoted expression
```

Fixing the line in the posted code:

```
queryId=$(aws logs start-query --log-group-name "$lambdas" --start-time 1695704400 --end-time 1695707999 --query-string 'filter @message like "requestId" | parse @message "operationName: '"'*'"'," as API | parse @message "status: *," as Status | parse @message "channel: '"'*'"'," as Channel | stats count(*) as Total by API,Channel,Status | sort API,Total desc' | jq '.queryId' | awk -F '"' '{print $2}')
```

Although this was not the real issue, it's still good to fix.

Comment: @joms Ah, we could actually see this in your updated question: results were simply not available, you need to repeat the query until the results are ready at AWS side. I amended my answer, I added a loop you can use that waits until the results are available.

Comment: I saw your updated post. its amazing how you able to structure that code logic. , i was having hard time to determine a condition statement for this kind of loop, Ill review your code and learn from it. Once again thank you.

Comment: Happy to help! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue. It was due to the bash script runs too fast, that the aws script was not able to finish its process or get its data. So I tried to put a sleep command for 5 seconds first to check if really that's the case. Then yes, that was the issue, so i'll just put a condition statement instead of sleep... Thank you all for your suggestion and I learned a lot from you guys.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).